# Declared variable is asking for value after value is set in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am having a problem with my variables. I am receiving the value of the variable email through an argument from an external program. When inside the For Next loop it contains the correct value but when it exits the loop it suddenly has no value. How would I go about exiting the loop and maintaining the value of the email variable.

```
Option Strict On

Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization

Module jrConnect

    Sub Main(ByVal cmdArgs() As String)
        Dim cs As String = "serverinfo"
        Dim conn As New MySqlConnection(cs)
        Dim entID As String
        Dim email As String

        Dim returnValue As Integer = 0

        If cmdArgs.Length > 0 Then
            For argNum As Integer = 0 To UBound(cmdArgs, 1)
                Console.Write("your email address is " & cmdArgs(argNum))
                email = cmdArgs(argNum)
                'value of email is set
            Next argNum

        End If

        Try

            conn.Open()
            Console.Write("Connected")
            Dim stm As String = "SELECT ###### FROM ###### WHERE email =" & "'" & email & "'"
            'the email variable at this point has no value

            Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(stm, conn)
            Dim reader As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

            While reader.Read()
                entID = reader.GetString(0)
            End While
            reader.Close()

            Dim stm2 = "SELECT value FROM ###### WHERE ###### = " & entID
            Dim cmd2 As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(stm2, conn)
            Dim reader2 As MySqlDataReader = cmd2.ExecuteReader()
            Dim counter As Integer = 0

            While reader2.Read() And counter < 3
                Console.WriteLine(reader2.GetString(0) & "%")
                counter = counter + 1
            End While
            reader.Close()

        Catch ex As MySqlException
        Finally
            conn.Close()
        End Try

    End Sub

End Module
```

the error im getting....
http://hostthenpost.org/uploads/a66f3efbf2eba24cef0f4e8536111b54.png

I changed it up a bit and added all the db processes to a function and tried to just pass the email variable to the function but it is printing the email address but not sending it to the function. Here is the new code.

```
Option Strict Off

Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization

Module jrConnect

    Sub Main(ByVal cmdArgs() As String)
        Dim temp As String = "spkelly86@gmail.com"
        'MsgBox("The Main procedure is starting the application.")
        Dim returnValue As Integer = 0
        ' See if there are any arguments.
        If cmdArgs.Length > 0 Then
            temp = cmdArgs(0)
            Console.Write(temp & " IN VB!")
            DBConnect(temp)
        End If
        ' Insert call to appropriate starting place in your code.
        'MsgBox("The application is terminating.")




    End Sub

    Function DBConnect(ByVal email As String)

        Dim cs As String = "serverinfo"
        Dim conn As New MySqlConnection(cs)
        Dim entID As String
        Try

            conn.Open()
            Dim stm As String = "SELECT ****** FROM ******** WHERE email =" & "'" & email & "'"
            Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(stm, conn)
            Dim reader As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

            While reader.Read()
                entID = reader.GetString(0)
            End While
            reader.Close()

            Dim stm2 = "SELECT value FROM ****** WHERE ****** = " & entID
            Dim cmd2 As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(stm2, conn)
            Dim reader2 As MySqlDataReader = cmd2.ExecuteReader()
            Dim counter As Integer = 0

            While reader2.Read() And counter < 3
                Console.WriteLine(reader2.GetString(0) & "%")
                counter = counter + 1
            End While
            reader.Close()

        Catch ex As MySqlException
        Finally
            conn.Close()
        End Try
        Return 0
    End Function
End Module
```

Comment: *sidenote:* [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) vulnerabilities spotted..

Comment: You will only target the last value in the `cmdArgs`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. The sql injection prevention is managed in the program sending the arguments :) It is only passing the one argument so how would i go about leaving the loop and still maintain the value of 'email'?

Comment: Have you used the debugger to go step by step and see at what point exactly the variable is emptied ?

Comment: is there a way to run the debugger and send the arguments? the program calling the vb script is an nsis installer.

Comment: `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break () ` will start the debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't exit the loop when the variable is set.

Try this:

```
Dim email As String = "dummy@email.com"
For argNum As Integer = 0 To UBound(cmdArgs, 1)
    Console.Write("your email address is " & cmdArgs(argNum))
    email = cmdArgs(argNum)
    'value of email is set
    Exit For
Next argNum
```

or the equivalent:

```
Dim email As String = "dummy@email.com"
If cmdArgs.Length > 0 Then
    Console.Write("your email address is " & cmdArgs(0))
    email = cmdArgs(0)
End If
```

Comment: I tried both of them but it is still stating "Variable 'email' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime." but only when i call it in the sql statement

Comment: Try to assign a dummy value to 'email' first (I've updated the code).